# Where can I find if there are updates or changes in the Geocoding API or the Place Autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

Where can I find if there are updates or changes in the Geocoding API or the Place Autocomplete API? Is there a release note page.

Besides the changes is there a page where I can find a roadmap of the API?

Answer (score 0):

For maps news and updates in general there's Google Maps Platform's [Blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform).

There are Release Notes for JavaScript API and for the mobile (Maps and Places) SDKs. But not for Geocoding or Places for web specifically. For e.g. JavaScript API see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases).

If by roadmap you mean a get started walk through the Maps APIs, I recommend you start with Google's [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started) documentation. The [API Picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker) is especially useful in understanding what each Maps service offers.

Hope this helps you!